# .htaccess rewrite to subdirectory joomla

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a static html home page.

I have a joomla installation at /blog/

I have a sub-blog  at /blog/my-sub-blog

I want to it to show up in the browser as just /my-sub-blog

So I use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^my-sub-blog/?$   /blog/my-sub-blog/  [NC]
```

And the result is an "article not found" 404 in joomla.

If i add the redirect flag just for testing, it redirects just fine and works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^my-sub-blog/?$   /blog/my-sub-blog/  [NC,R]
```

But I want it to invisibly rewrite, not redirect.
Any suggestions on how to get it to silently rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that joomla is looking at the REQUEST_URI and similar server variables which would show up as something different because the request is actually `/my-sub-blog/` and not `/blog/my-sub-blog/` like it's expecting. The easiest way to get around this is to have mod_proxy loaded, and internally proxy the request instead of redirecting the browser:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^my-sub-blog/?$   /blog/my-sub-blog/  [NC,P,L]
```

or better yet:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^my-sub-blog/?(.*)$   /blog/my-sub-blog/$1  [NC,P,L]
```